# Toggling HTML menus on click with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am Korean beginner in HTML. I've been doing this for a few days, and I got each menu to display when pressed. However, the problem is that when you click the hat, the hat menus appear, but when you click another menu, the hat menu disappears, and I want the clicked menus to appear. What should I do? And the source is too long, it doesn't look good for me either.

HTML

```
           ----------sidebar----------------
            <div class="menu" id="cap"><p>모자</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu" id="costume"><p>상의</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="outer"><p>아우터</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="onepice"><p>원피스</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="pant"><p>하의</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="shoes"><p>신발</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="bag"><p>가방</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="accessory"><p>액세서리</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="menu" id="sports"><p>스포츠</p>
            </div>
             ----------sidebar---------------- 
            <div class="caps" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">모자</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">볼캡</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">비니</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">버킷</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">헌팅</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">페도라</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">트루퍼</a>    
            </div>
            <div class="costumes" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">상의</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">반팔 </a>
                <a href="javascript:;">긴팔</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">후드티</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">카라티</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">셔츠</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">니트</a>
            </div>        
            <div class="outers" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">아우터</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">후드 집업</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">가디건</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">슈트</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">재킷</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">코트</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">패딩</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">베스트</a>
            </div> 
            <div class="onepices" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">원피스</div>
                <a href="javascript:;l">미니 원피스</a>
                =<a href="javascript:;">미디 원피스</a>
                =<a href="javascript:;">맥시 원피스</a>  
            </div> 
            <div class="pants" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">바지</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">청바지</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">면바지</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">반바지</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">슬랙스</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">레깅스</a> 
            </div> 
            <div class="bags" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">가방</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">백 팩</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">크로스 백</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">숄더 백</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">클러치 백</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">웨이스트 백</a>            
                <a href="javascript:;">캐리어</a>  
            </div> 
            <div class="shoess" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">신발</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">캔버스</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">단화</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">런닝화</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">축구화</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">샌들</a> 
            </div> 
            <div class="accessorys" id="menu_list">
                <div class="top">액세서리</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">안경</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">마스크</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">스카프</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">머플러</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">넥타이</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">장갑</a>  
            </div> 
            <div class="sportss" id="menu_list" >
                <div class="top">스포츠</div>
                <a href="javascript:;">수영용품</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">수영복</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">기능성 상의</a>
                <a href="javascript:;">기능성 하의</a>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cap").click(function(){
    $(".caps").toggle();
});
$("#costume").click(function(){
    $(".costumes").toggle();
});
$("#outer").click(function(){
    $(".outers").toggle();
});
$("#onepice").click(function(){
    $(".onepices").toggle();
});
$("#pant").click(function(){
    $(".pants").toggle();
});
$("#bag").click(function(){
    $(".bags").toggle();
});
$("#shoes").click(function(){
    $(".shoess").toggle();
});
$("#accessory").click(function(){
    $(".accessorys").toggle();
});
$("#sports").click(function(){
    $(".sportss").toggle();
});
```

css

```
#menu_list{
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
background-color: lawngreen;
display: none;}
```

Comment: why using so many click events ?

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use so many click events instead give custom-attribute to your div element where this value matches with `id` value of `menu` .Then,just get that `id` value whenever `.menu` is clicked and show div where matching value is i.e : `$(".menu_list[data-id=" + id + "]")`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $('.menu_list').css('display', 'none'); //hide
  //check if menu has active clas
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    //remove same
    $(this).removeClass("active")
  } else {
    //remove from other menus
    $(".menu").not(this).removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active") //add active
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //show div where data-id matches
    $(".menu_list[data-id=" + id + "]").css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu_list {
  height: 250%;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lawngreen;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
----------sidebar----------------
<div class="menu" id="cap">
  <p>모자</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="costume">
  <p>상의</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="outer">
  <p>아우터</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="onepice">
  <p>원피스</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="pant">
  <p>하의</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="shoes">
  <p>신발</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="bag">
  <p>가방</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="accessory">
  <p>액세서리</p>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="sports">
  <p>스포츠</p>
</div>
----------sidebar----------------
<!--added data-id which macthes id of menu-->
<div data-id="cap" class="caps menu_list">
  <div class="top">모자</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">볼캡</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">비니</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">버킷</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">헌팅</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">페도라</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">트루퍼</a>
</div>
<div data-id="cap" class="costumes menu_list">
  <div class="top">상의</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">반팔 </a>
  <a href="javascript:;">긴팔</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">후드티</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">카라티</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">셔츠</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">니트</a>
</div>
<div data-id="outer" class="outers menu_list">
  <div class="top">아우터</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">후드 집업</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">가디건</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">슈트</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">재킷</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">코트</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">패딩</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">베스트</a>
</div>
<div data-id="onepice" class="onepices menu_list">
  <div class="top">원피스</div>
  <a href="javascript:;l">미니 원피스</a> =
  <a href="javascript:;">미디 원피스</a> =
  <a href="javascript:;">맥시 원피스</a>
</div>
<div data-id="pant" class="pants menu_list">
  <div class="top">바지</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">청바지</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">면바지</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">반바지</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">슬랙스</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">레깅스</a>
</div>
<div data-id="bag" class="bags menu_list">
  <div class="top">가방</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">백 팩</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">크로스 백</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">숄더 백</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">클러치 백</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">웨이스트 백</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">캐리어</a>
</div>
<div data-id="shoes" class="shoess menu_list">
  <div class="top">신발</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">캔버스</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">단화</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">런닝화</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">축구화</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">샌들</a>
</div>
<div data-id="accessory" class="accessorys menu_list">
  <div class="top">액세서리</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">안경</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">마스크</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">스카프</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">머플러</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">넥타이</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">장갑</a>
</div>
<div data-id="sports" class="sportss menu_list">
  <div class="top">스포츠</div>
  <a href="javascript:;">수영용품</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">수영복</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">기능성 상의</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">기능성 하의</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I want. Thank you very much. However, I am still a beginner. You need to understand the answer.

Comment: Hi, let me know if you have any doubt in above demo code .

Comment: thank you. I will come to ask questions tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you yesterday, I didn't understand JavaScript, so $('.menu_list').css('display','none'); Why did this add up? The .menu_list is already hidden.

Comment: hi everytime you click on menu new `menu_list` should show up so this line will hide other menu_list and then using `$(".menu_list[data-id=" + id + "]").css('display', 'block');` will show only menu_list which has been clicked.

Comment: Does JavaScript first execute the if statement?

Comment: yes first `if` is executed then else part(if condition doesn't meet)

Comment: $(".menu").not(this).removeClass("active") What does this mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225867/discussion-between-swati-and-).

Answer (score 0):

When toggling, you can add a class to it, like `active`:

```js
$("#cap").click(function() {
  $(".caps").toggle();
  document.querySelector(".caps").classList.add("active");
});
```

Well, what was that for? It's like a mark. We have marked that this menu is opened.

Then in our code we can simply look for the marked menu and remove the class:

```
$("#cap").click(function() {
  $(".caps").toggle();
  document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(".caps").classList.add("active");
});
```

I think I understood you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want?

- Also, id should be unique per 'html page' so, if you want to use `menu-list` multiple times, add it to `class` NOT `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu_list').css('display', 'none');
  });

  $("#cap").click(function(){
    $(".caps").toggle();
  });
  $("#costume").click(function(){
      $(".costumes").toggle();
  });
  $("#outer").click(function(){
      $(".outers").toggle();
  });
  $("#onepice").click(function(){
      $(".onepices").toggle();
  });
  $("#pant").click(function(){
      $(".pants").toggle();
  });
  $("#bag").click(function(){
      $(".bags").toggle();
  });
  $("#shoes").click(function(){
      $(".shoess").toggle();
  });
  
  $("#accessory").click(function(){
      $(".accessorys").toggle();
  });
  $("#sports").click(function(){
      $(".sports").toggle();
  });
 });
```

```css
.menu {
  background:orange;
  width:100px;
}

.menu_list{
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------sidebar---------------- -->
<div class="menu" id="cap"><p>모자</p></div>
<div class="menu" id="costume"><p>상의</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="outer"><p>아우터</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="onepice"><p>원피스</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="pant"><p>하의</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="shoes"><p>신발</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="bag"><p>가방</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="accessory"><p>액세서리</p></div> 
<div class="menu" id="sports"><p>스포츠</p></div>

<!----------sidebar---------------- -->
<div class="caps menu_list">
    <div class="top">모자</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">볼캡</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">비니</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">버킷</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">헌팅</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">페도라</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">트루퍼</a>    
</div>
<div class="costumes menu_list">
    <div class="top">상의</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">반팔 </a>
    <a href="javascript:;">긴팔</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">후드티</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">카라티</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">셔츠</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">니트</a>
</div>        
<div class="outers menu_list">
    <div class="top">아우터</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">후드 집업</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">가디건</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">슈트</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">재킷</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">코트</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">패딩</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">베스트</a>
</div> 
<div class="onepices menu_list">
    <div class="top">원피스</div>
    <a href="javascript:;l">미니 원피스</a>
    =<a href="javascript:;">미디 원피스</a>
    =<a href="javascript:;">맥시 원피스</a>  
</div> 
<div class="pants menu_list">
    <div class="top">바지</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">청바지</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">면바지</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">반바지</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">슬랙스</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">레깅스</a> 
</div> 
<div class="bags menu_list">
    <div class="top">가방</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">백 팩</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">크로스 백</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">숄더 백</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">클러치 백</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">웨이스트 백</a>            
    <a href="javascript:;">캐리어</a>  
</div> 
<div class="shoess menu_list">
    <div class="top">신발</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">캔버스</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">단화</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">런닝화</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">축구화</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">샌들</a> 
</div> 
<div class="accessorys menu_list">
    <div class="top">액세서리</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">안경</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">마스크</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">스카프</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">머플러</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">넥타이</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">장갑</a>  
</div> 
<div class="sports menu_list">
    <div class="top">스포츠</div>
    <a href="javascript:;">수영용품</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">수영복</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">기능성 상의</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">기능성 하의</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. https://cablemaker.xyz/ What I want is this way. If you ask too many, you can refuse. It disappears when you press the same menu.